# Automatically group verb conjugations with machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy

Is it possible to automatically group verb conjugations that belong together? From a big Wikipedia dataset, I would like to extract all verbs, group them together based on the all the tense and put them into conjugation tables.

**Present**

> (I) eat
>
> (You) eat
>
> ...

**Past Present**

> (I) ate
>
> (You) ate
>
> ...

Would this be possible with machine learning? I found spacy.io that I can use to identify whether a word is a verb or not, but I have no idea how I would be able to "group" them automatically.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question involves a number of sub-problems.  It will help you to be familiar with the nomenclature so you can find existing tools and solutions to these problems.

To do this task, you need to:

1. Identify which tokens in the Wikipedia dataset are verbs.
2. For each of these verb tokens, identify the conjugation being used.
3. For each of these verb tokens, identify the lemma of the verb (otherwise known as the "dictionary form").  This will tell you which "group" the token belongs to.

The first task is usually done by a POS-tagger.  A POS-tagger scans a text's tokens and identifies the part-of-speech of each.

The second sub-task is known generally as "morphological analysis", and tools that do it are known as morphological analyzers.  Some POS-taggers will also give you this information, which you can tell by looking at the tagset used by the tagger.  However, even when they provide conjugation information, it is often not as detailed as would be provided by a morphological analyzer.

Lastly, the third task is known as lemmatization.  Most POS-taggers and morphological analyzers will provide you with the lemma.

There are many methods and tools that have been created for all these tasks.  Many of these involve machine learning methods.  The lab I worked in used neural networks trained on supervised datasets to do morphological analysis, for example.  These tools can take a long time to build and tune, though, and there are off-the-shelf solutions for major languages (especially English).

I do not know what tools are state-of-the-art for English off the top of my head.  But, now that you know the terminology, you can survey what tools are available yourself.  I can see from the documentation page that Spacy does give you most of the information you need: it identifies the verbs and provides the lemma.  It also seems to distinguish some conjugations with different "tags" (e.g. "VBG" and "VBZ").  There's a full list here under "Part-of-Speech Tagging": https://spacy.io/api/annotation.  Not sure if those tags will cover all the conjugations you're concerned with, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply! It is clear to me know how to continue. Thanks again! :-)